# How to fix no data in downloaded file

Tags: swift, download

I am trying to download a file from a server, to be exact, a mp3 file. It downloads just fine, and I assume because of the time it takes to download a file, it actually works. But when I try to output the downloaded content to a file the file Size is 0 kb.

```
func download(downloadURL: String) {
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            var fileContent = "";
            let saveFilePath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] + "/test.mp3";
            //DOWNLOAD DATA FROM SERVER
            let url = URL(string: downloadURL)!
            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:url) { (data, response, error) in
                if error != nil {
                   print(error!)
                }
                else {
                    if let textFile = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8) {
                        print(textFile)
                        fileContent = textFile
                    }
                }
                //SAVE DATA TO FILE
                let data: Data = Data(fileContent.utf8)
                if (FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: saveFilePath)) {
                    do {
                        try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: URL(string: saveFilePath)!)
                    } catch {
                        print("ERROR")
                    }
                }

                FileManager.default.createFile(atPath: saveFilePath, contents: data)
                print("Saving file in Directory: " + saveFilePath)

                if (FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: String(saveFilePath))) {
                    print("File saved successfully!")
                } else {
                    print("Something went wrong!")
                }
            }
            task.resume()
        }

    }
```

There are no error messages, so I don't know why nothing is saved in the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making a common mistake:

`URL(string` is the wrong API for file system URLs. You **must** use `URL(fileURLWithPath`.

However you can avoid the error if you use always the URL related API and you can save the downloaded data directly to disk without conversion to `String` and back to `Data`

```
func download(downloadURL: String) {
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        let saveFileURL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false).appendingPathComponent("/test.mp3")
        let url = URL(string: downloadURL)!
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:url) { (data, response, error) in
            if let error = error { print(error); return }
            if (FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: saveFileURL.path)) {
                do {
                    try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: saveFileURL)
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
            do {
                try data!.write(to: saveFileURL)
                print("File saved successfully!")
            } catch {
                print("Something went wrong!", error)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```